# skipping null fields in Big Query inserts from Dataflow

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am just wondering if we can skip the null fields from the Json messages to reduce the serialisation overhead and also making the big query insert faster by reducing the query size?

Comment: Do you have more context? Code? It should be pretty easy to test with a minimal example.

Comment: If we don't do that now, it sounds like a good improvement. https://beam.apache.org/contribute/